# How do I load data from sql server to Bing Ajax Map Control?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

This is driving me nuts. It seems like it should be more striaght forward. I have a Bing Map and as long as I hardcode lat & long in the javascript it works.

I'm trying to figure out how to pass coordinates in from an ASP.NET to the javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. One option is to use the AJAX Map DataConnector which uses MVC framework to connect a SQL database to Bing Maps: http://ajaxmapdataconnector.codeplex.com/

Another method is to use the Entity Framework and create a custom web service. I've written two blogs recently on how to do this here:

http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/07/31/how-to-create-a-spatial-web-service-that-connects-a-database-to-bing-maps-using-ef5.aspx

http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/08/05/advance-spatial-queries-using-entity-framework-5.aspx